# text inside links CKeditor

Tags: css, ckeditor

I want to change style of link. I wrote btn1 and btn2 styles in document.css. This is my modal window:

```
{
    id: "view",
    label: b.view,
    title: b.view,
    elements: [{ 
      type:"select", id:"typeButton", label:b.typeButton, "default":"notSet", style:"width : 100%;", items:[[c.notSet,""], [b.blueButton, "btn2"],[b.grayButton, "btn1"]], "default":"", onChange:m, setup:h, commit:j }
    ]
}
```

and my onOk function

```
onOk: function(){
    var a = {};
    this.commitContent(a);
    var dialog = this;
    var link = g.document.createElement( 'a' );

    link.setAttribute( 'href', a.url.protocol + a.url.url );
    var classes = dialog.getValueOf( 'view', 'typeButton' );
    link.setAttribute( 'class', classes );
    link.setText();
    g.insertElement( link );
}
```

My main problem is that I don't know how to insert my text inside the link. Now I have an empty link with my styles and nearby href of this link. It must work such way:

- you typing some text
- accentuation it
- appears dialog window
- you choose the style of the link
- Press OK and usuall text placed in the block with the specified styles (looks like bootstrap buttons)

How can i get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried adding anything to setText?

Comment: if i add something, for example link.setText('Hello');
i will have button with text 'hello' and near another button, with text, which i wrote in my dialog window as a link(in my dialog window you may set link, when you click on the text that you typed you will pass the link ). I want that inside button there was a text, which i allocated and typing at first.